# bind() error in multicast sender/receiver program

Tags: c, sockets, multicast

hi i am writting a multicast code which does the following:

1)it takes multicast group ip and port on command line. It joins the group and waits for messages.
2)It sends a "hello-" + time() every 15 seconds to count how many members are present in the group.
3)Any member who receives "hello-"+time(), simply echoes the same.
The member which has sent hello, counts the replies received within 5 seconds and displays count on the screen.

but i have to implement it in a single file. for reciving part i am attatching a snipet of code

```
#define EXAMPLE_PORT 6000
#define EXAMPLE_GROUP "239.0.0.1"

####


    sockrecv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
       if (sockrecv < 0) {
         perror("socket send");
         exit(1);
       }
       bzero((char *)&addrrecv, sizeof(addrrecv));
       addrrecv.sin_family = AF_INET;
       addrrecv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
       addrrecv.sin_port = htons(EXAMPLE_PORT);
       addrlenrecv = sizeof(addrrecv);

       if (bind(sockrecv, (struct sockaddr *) &addrrecv, sizeof(addrrecv)) < 0) {        
             perror("bind");
         exit(1);
          }    
          mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(EXAMPLE_GROUP);         
          mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);         
          if (setsockopt(sockrecv, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,
                 &mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0) {
         perror("setsockopt mreq");
         exit(1);
          }
```

the problem is to test it i have to run multiple copies on my system.first time program runs fine

but on second execution bind() call gives error as a socket is already attached to that port no.

but if the program has to receive message from a group it has bind the socket to the specific ip and port no .

so how can i test it on a single system...???

Answer (score 1):

Only one instance of your program can `bind` to EXAMPLE_PORT. While your first instance is running you cannot start another for it will try binding to EXAMPLE_PORT which is already in use. Hence the bind error you see.

Clients need not `bind`. You create a socket and do `sendto` and `recvfrom` You can create multiple instance of client. No issues here. (Of course there shall be limit of how many `socket`s can be created)

Servers need to `bind`. And in a system you can have only one instance of your UDP program running bound to one specific port.

Answer (score 0):

You always need to close the socket after you have done everything using:

```
close(int sockfd);
```

Otherwise the port keeps blocked until the socket attached to it times out (mostly between 30 and 180 seconds).